# How to create a vector with character string and corresponding number for each repeat

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, repeat

Hi I am trying to create a vector which has this information user_1, through user_33 so that I can easily copy and paste this information into a .y purrr function. I was looking at using rep(user_, [1:33]) but do not understand the syntax of how to create the output I am looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `paste` or `paste0`. The second argument is vectorized, so it'll give you the full vector.

```r
paste("user", 1:33, sep = "_")
paste0("user_", 1:33)
```

output

```r
 [1] "user_1"  "user_2"  "user_3"  "user_4"  "user_5"  "user_6"  "user_7"  "user_8" 
 [9] "user_9"  "user_10" "user_11" "user_12" "user_13" "user_14" "user_15" "user_16"
[17] "user_17" "user_18" "user_19" "user_20" "user_21" "user_22" "user_23" "user_24"
[25] "user_25" "user_26" "user_27" "user_28" "user_29" "user_30" "user_31" "user_32"
[33] "user_33"
```

Comment: thank you, is there a way to add a comma after each entry? So "user_1", "user_2", "user_3",...

Comment: Do you mean `toString(paste0("user_", 1:33))`?

Comment: `stringr::str_c("user_", 1:33)` as an alternative ;)

Comment: @Maël Kind of but no, not what I am looking for as you lose the quotation marks. I was looking for something so I didn't have to manually enter commas in after pasting my data in an argument. i.e "user_1", "user_2", "user_3", ...... the toString command made to look like this "user_1, user_2, user_3, ..... which in that case I would need to re insert the quotations instead of periods

Answer (score 0):

`cat(paste0("'", paste0("user_", 1:33), "', "))` would produce output you could copy and paste, i.e., 'user_1',  'user_2',  'user_3', ...